# Unable to sort configurable products based on attribute value and price

Tags: magento-1.7

Am new to Magento. Am unable to sort the products in my shopping cart based on price and attribute name -- qty. My attribute values are 750 ml, 500ml, 200ml and they have their respective price. Sorting using only price is working but i dnt know how to sort using the attribute value. The below code displays the minimum price value. But i want to display the minimum price value of the minimum attribute value

```
echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to edit you attribute (in Attribute management) to be **shown in product listing** and **Used for Sorting in product listing**

[image]

In this way you are sure that the attribute is selected in the collection and it's available from the catalog/product template pages.

Comment: Its already set in the Manage Attributes.

Used in Product Listing is Yes
Used for Sorting in Product Listing is Yes

Comment: Please, be more specific in your question. Provide more informations about the attributes, the values.
What do you want to sort? The products in the category page?
Cheers